# Trying to get Python to read a specific CSV file

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a program that will show CSVs in a directory, and then you can put in the number of the file, and it will show what is written in the .CSV file. I've gotten everything to work, except when I put in a number, it shows me what's written in that CSV and then all the CSVs after it.

```
def seeProject():
    y = 1
    p = 0
    for x in os.listdir():
        if x.endswith(".csv"):
            print(str(y)+". "+ x)
            y = y+1
    f = input("Which would you like to open?\n")
    for x in os.listdir():
        if x.endswith (".csv") and p == int(f):
            j = open(x,"r")
            for w in j:
                print(w)
        else:
            p += 1
            continue
```

I tried changing the p value and that didn't work. I did experiment with opening a specific file by name, and that worked but some of the future files have really long names and I would rather just pick the file number. When I put in 1 I get:

```
1. Herman.csv
2. Jemma.csv
Which would you like to open?
1
EROEIER,EEROIWEN,EOTIHNWET,0,WOIRH(*,WHR(*WR,WRUIWRH8,WRHWR*

WRWRIUWBT,OIEGE,EPORTE(Tb,0,OEIRHWER(,WER(*WE,WBRUI8,IWBR8
```

Putting in 2 gets me:

```
1. Herman.csv
2. Jemma.csv
Which would you like to open?
2
WRWRIUWBT,OIEGE,EPORTE(Tb,0,OEIRHWER(,WER(*WE,WBRUI8,IWBR8
``
```

Comment: You need to initialize `p` to `1`, just like `y`.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I set P to 1 it doesn't show anything when 1 is inputted, and it shows everything when 2 is inputted.

Comment: @JohnGordon I deleted that comment because I wrote an answer that says the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I found 2 problems

1. You initialize `y = 1`, but `p = 0`, thus incurs an *off-by-one* error
2. When you found your file and display the content, you did not increase `p` by one. Thus subsequent files will be displayed.

Here is the fix your for code:

```py
import os


def seeProject():
    y = 1
    p = 1  # <-- Init to 1
    for x in os.listdir():
        if x.endswith(".csv"):
            print(str(y) + ". " + x)
            y = y + 1
    f = input("Which would you like to open?\n")
    for x in os.listdir():
        if x.endswith(".csv"):
            if p == int(f):  # <-- Create a separate if statement
                print(f"{x=}")
                j = open(x, "r")
                for w in j:
                    print(w)
            p = p + 1  # <-- Increase for all the .csv files


seeProject()
```

Notes

- Please do not use single-letter variable names: they are cryptic, not telling what they are for. Please look at other's solution and see how they name their variables
- This post is helping you to spot the error. Consider studying others' solution: they are simpler easier to follow

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're incrementing `p` only for the non-CSV files. But your whole approach is much more complicated than needed.

Put all the CSV files into a list, which you can do easily with `glob.glob()`. Then print the list to create the menu, and use the user's input as an index into the list.

```
import glob

def seeProject():
    csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
    for i, filename in enumerate(csv_files, 1):
        print(f'{i}. {filename}')

    while True:
        f = int(input("Which would you like to open?\n"))
        if 1 <= f <= len(csv_files):
            break
        print(f"Enter a number between 1 and {len(csv_files)}")
    filename = csv_files[f-1]
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a dict of files then choose file from dict:

```
endswith='.csv' 
files = {str(k):v for k,v in enumerate([i for i in os.listdir() if i.endswith(endswith)],1)}
for k,v in files.items(): print(k,v)
fname = files.get(input('file number '),None)
if fname:
    with open(fname) as fn:
        # do your stuff
```

Comment: Why a dict instead of a list?

Comment: For me dict makes file number on list to file name mapping easier. files.get(input('file number '),None) returns selected file name or None if input value not in files.

Comment: Note input() returns str, list indices are int. Wrong input can result in  ValueError or IndexError. Of course you can use try/except to catch them, but dict approach has no such problem.